# Inductive type constructors with the defined type appearing in non-strictly positive position

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In the HoTT book §5.6 ‘The general syntax of inductive definitions’ there is a proof that the existence of an inductive type $T$ with a constructor $t : ((T \to \mathsf{Prop}) \to \mathsf{Prop}) \to T$ is inconsistent with propositional resizing.

Suppose, however, that propositional resizing is rejected. Is there a setting (perhaps other than type theory) where postulating this or an analogous construction makes sense?

Furthermore, a footnote later in that section states tat ‘[o]ne can consider various relaxations of [the strict positivity] condition’. What particular relaxations have been studied?

Comment: You might get an answer quicker on TCS.SE...